# Embed Bing map in fullscreen

Tags: embed, fullscreen, bing-maps

Does anuyone know if it is possible to embed a bing map in fullscreen??
So that the map can always fill the background and simply overlay a few elements on top.

I cannot seem to achieve that with 100% iframe and bing's help is not that helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you want to achieve the effect of having the map fill up the entire screen, sort of like using the map as a background, and then have other elements overlaid on top?  If so, you should be able to accomplish this easily via the position:fixed [CSS Property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp).

```
        <div id='yourMapDiv' style="position: fixed; top: 0px;
            left: 0px; right:0px; bottom:0px; z-index: 100">
        </div>
```

This is saying `yourMapDiv` will have a fixed position that is 0 pixel away from all four edges of the screen.  In effect, you are spanning `yourMapDiv` across the entire browser screen, without having to specify explicit length or width, and re-sizing will not causing scroll bars to appear:

[image]

Here is what going full screen in Chrome looks like:

[image]

In the example above I assigned a z-index of 100 to `yourMapDiv`, to illustrate that if you want other elements to appear above the map, you will have to assign a higher z-index to them.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Am I missing something? http://jsfiddle.net/dstarsboy/C284d/

Comment: It doesn't work because you applied the style to the parent div and not the iframe itself

Answer (score 2):

The answers above did not work for me.
To get a map fill out the browser window without any borders or scrollbars, I had to use the following minimal html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bing Map</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<style>
#myMap {
    height: 100%;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myMap"></div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>

    function GetMap() {
        new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'your_bing_key'
        });
    }
     </script>

    <script type='text/javascript' 
    src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer>
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't "embed a Bing Map in fullscreen", but it's certainly possible to use CSS to set the height and width of the div containing the map to be 100% of the browser, and then maximise (or set to fullscreen) the browser window - is that what you mean?