# bing map in fullpage width and height

Tags: html, css, bing-maps

is there any way, how to show bing map in iframe with full with?

my code is here, but I am not able to make it work. Even 100% width is not working.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title></title>
<!-- Styles Flexible iFrame -->
<style>
.Flexible-container {position: relative; padding-bottom: 56.25%; padding-top: 30px; height: 0; overflow: hidden;}
.Flexible-container iframe,   
.Flexible-container object,  
.Flexible-container embed {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
</style>
  </head>
  <body>




<!-- Responsive iFrame -->
<div class="Flexible-container">
    <iframe Name="mapFrame" scrolling="no" width="100%" height="512"  frameborder="0" src="//www.bing.com/maps/embed/?lvl=13&amp;cp=46.947954~7.444284&amp;sty=r&amp;draggable=true&amp;v=2&amp;dir=0&amp;where1=Bern%2C+Schweiz&amp;form=LMLTEW&amp;pp=46.948429107666016~7.440460205078125&amp;mkt=de-de&amp;gen=false&amp;emid=0268dbb0-0977-3717-0aff-4f79b8311370&amp;w=100%&amp;h=512"></iframe>
</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is the link it will fulfil your need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926576/embed-bing-map-in-fullscreen

Comment: the link mentioned is not working anymore. Bing maps in iframe contain width and height value in src url.